# passing R function arguments in rpy

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have the following two lines of code that both run fine in both R and Python (via Rpy):

```
[R] rcut = cut(vector, brks)
[Python] rcut = r.cut(vector, brks)
```

However, if I want to add the argument of `include.lowest=TRUE`, it runs as expected in R:

```
[R] rcut = cut(vector, brks, include.lowest=TRUE)
```

But it doesn't work in Rpy:

```
[Python] rcut = r.cut(vector, brks, include_lowest="TRUE")
```

which gives the following error:

```
rpy.RPy_RException: Error in ok && include.lowest : invalid 'y' type in 'x && y'
```

Do you know what might cause that and what should I do to make it work? Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know `rpy`, but could it be due to using `"TRUE"` (a character) instead of `TRUE` (a logical)?

EDIT: The `rpy` documentation seems to indicate using `r.TRUE`:

http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy/doc/rpy_html/R-boolean-objects.html#R-boolean-objects

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Rpy, but I would guess it needs to be `include_lowest=True` (No quotes, `True` is a boolean value in python.)